# Will uuid.NAMESPACE_URL generate unique deterministic UUIDs for different URLs?

Tags: python, python-3.x, uuid

Question: Will this piece of code generate `unique` (with very high probability) and `deterministic` (always) UUIDs for different URLs?

```
import uuid
uuid1 = uuid.uuid5(uuid.NAMESPACE_URL, 'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask1')
uuid2 = uuid.uuid5(uuid.NAMESPACE_URL, 'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask2')
```

ie.

- `uuid1 != uuid2  if url1 != url2` (uniqueness with very high probability),   and
- `url1 will always generate uuid1` (deterministic always)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was going to suggest running your namespace and string through a SHA hash function and then using the lower 128 bits for the UUID.

Turns out that's very similar what they do in Python for UUID5:

```
def uuid5(namespace, name):
     """Generate a UUID from the SHA-1 hash of a namespace UUID and a name."""
     from hashlib import sha1
     hash = sha1(namespace.bytes + bytes(name, "utf-8")).digest()
     return UUID(bytes=hash[:16], version=5)
```

https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3db42fc5aca320b0cac1895bc3cb731235ede794/Lib/uuid.py#L718

I think you would have to be pretty unlucky (like astronomically unlucky) for there to be a collision. And it's deterministic for sure.